# Ao inserir novo objeto em um array, todos os objetos do array são alterados

Tags: javascript, array

## Contexto

No evento `OnChange` do `input` de código de barras, eu realizo uma requisição AJAX que vai até o Banco de dados, seleciona o produto que possui aquele Código de barras e, devolve o objeto dele inteiro. Ao fazer isso, preciso inserir o mesmo num array de objetos JavaScript, porém, nesse momento vem o meu problema.

## Problema

Quando atualizo os atributos do objeto vindos com os dados do AJAX, e insiro no Array, caso o usuário queira um novo objeto (Produto), ele sobrescreve o mesmo objeto, sendo assim, tenho vários objetos dentro do Array, com os mesmos valores.

## Código JS

```
$("#cbarras").on('change', function() {
              
       var cbarras = $('#cbarras').val();
       var cliente =  $('#cliente').val(); 
       var data = $('#data_compra').val();
       var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val();
          
       if (cbarras && cliente && data && quantidade){
           $.ajax({
             url : "http://localhost:8080/ProjBiltiful/BuscarProduto.jsp?id=" + cbarras,
             dataType : "json",
             success : function(data){
             if (data){
                 var total_item = data.vvenda * quantidade;
                 total += total_item;
                 $('#total_venda').val(total);
                    
                 //INCLUO OS ITENS DA VENDA EM UM ARRAY DE OBJETOS
                 obj_itens.cbarras = data.cbarras;
                 obj_itens.valor = data.vvenda;
                 obj_itens.qtd = quantidade;
                 obj_itens.total = total_item;
                 
                 
                 itens_venda.push(obj_itens);
                 
                 obj_itens.cbarras = 0;
                 obj_itens.valor = data.vvenda;
                 obj_itens.qtd = 0;
                 obj_itens.total = 0;
                 
                 console.log(itens_venda);
                 
                 $('#table_itens tbody').append(
                   '<tr class="child">'
                      + '<td align="center">' + data.cbarras + '</td>'
                      + '<td align="center">' + data.nome + '</td>'
                      + '<td align="center">' + data.vvenda + '</td>'
                      + '<td align="center">' + quantidade + '</td>'
                      + '<td align="center">' + total_item + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                 );

                  } else {
                    alert('Produto não encontrado !');
                  }
              },
                error: function(err){
                  alert('Ooops... Encontramos um erro ao buscar o produto');
                }
            });
        } else {
          alert("Você deve ter esquecido de preencher algum campo da venda!");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No seu código, você não mostrou onde você está definindo `obj_itens`, mas percebe-se que não está declarado dentro do escopo da função anônima passada como *callback* à chave *success*.

Objetos são sempre tratados como "*referência*" em JavaScript. Isto quer dizer que, a cada invocação desta função, você está sobrescrevendo o mesmo objeto.

Na verdade, diferentemente do que você disse, você não tem vários objetos no Array, mas você está adicionando o **mesmo objeto** de novo, e a cada vez que você atualiza o valor dele, isto se aplica a todos itens do Array (pois é o mesmo objeto/mesma referência).

Para solucionar isto, você deve criar um novo objeto dentro da sua função e adicionar na Array este novo objeto. Algo assim:

```
$.ajax({
   /* ... */
   success : function(data){

    /* ... */

    var novo_item = {}; //novo objeto

    novo_item.cbarras = data.cbarras;
    novo_item.valor = data.vvenda;
    novo_item.qtd = quantidade;
    novo_item.total = total_item;


    itens_venda.push(novo_item);

    console.log(itens_venda);

    /* ... */


  } /*, ... */
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: mrlew, MUITO OBRIGADO! ME AJUDOU MUITO, era isso mesmo, eu sabia que estava com o mesmo objeto, mas não sabia como mudar isso! De verdade, me ajudou muito! Eu pensei que teria que modificar toda a arquitetura da minha lógica! Como faço para te dar a maior pontuação existente nesse Fórum? Sou novo aqui também! Obrigado, sucesso!!!

Comment: +1 pela boa resposta.
@MatheusMinguini
Basta dar um upvote na respota dele e marcar como solução.

Comment: Ok, obrigado, galera! Vocês são demais!

Comment: @MatheusMinguini obrigado rsrs que bom que funcionou. Boa sorte no projeto!

Comment: @wilker obrigado! Abraços!